# Rebasing in order to integrate changes (not in the context of pull requests)?

Tags: git, rebase

I've only been able to find info on rebasing in the context of pull requests, but what I'm wanting to do is unrelated to pull requests. My situation is as follows:

I've committed some changes to my fork of my company's software, let's call this commit x. After this commit I sent a PR to my coworker's fork.

I then made more changes. I haven't committed those yet; they're in my working tree at the moment.

Turns out I made some mistakes in commit x and my coworker fixed them and committed the changes to his fork, let's call his commit commit y. So his most recent commit is y.

Is there a way to rebase (or some other operation, if this is not the correct use of rebase) my fork onto his, such that my recent commit is y (x would then be the second most recent commit), while also keeping my working tree changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer yes, there are several ways to handle this. Here is what I find the easiest:

1. start on your branch,

```
git checkout -b [copy-of-working-branch-with-commit-x-and-commit-y]
```

to make a copy of your branch as-is

2. `git checkout [original-working-branch-with-commit-x-and-commit-y]` and

```
git reset --hard [remote-branch]
```

with your co-worker's pushed changes (reminder: this will overwrite commit-y!)

3. Finally you can

```
git cherry-pick [sha for most recent commit-y-from-copy-branch]
```

and that should do it!

Comment: Thank you! Would cherry picking commit y put it into my history, such that the log would look like `....commit x -> commit y -> current working tree` ?

Also, not quite understanding the hard reset part. Isn't resetting meant for reverting to a previous commit? How can I hard reset to a commit that isn't in my branch (since my branch/fork doesn't have commit y)? 

Sorry for being slow, I appreciate the help!

Comment: Make a copy of your branch first. Once your coworker pushes to your working branch after a rebase, you cannot pull your branch without merge conflicts and a big mess. Assuming you are working on origin together, you'll need `git reset --hard origin [branch]` Reset --hard will set your head to the current state of the HEAD @origin. Then, when you cherry-pick your most recent commit from your old copy of the branch, it will only bring in the changes on that new commit. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: If you're uncertain, just make an extra copy of the branch and/or do a dry run. You can always delete copies of branches -- they are cheap. Cleaning up a merged or rebased branch is expensive (ie. takes a lot of time and effort).

Comment: Gotcha, just one thing: is it possible to do this between different forks? I can checkout a branch on a different fork (I'd just have to have that fork as a remote), but how would I specify the fork that the cherry-picks should be applied to? Haven't been able to find the syntax for that. Note that the branches we're working on on our respective forks have the same name, not sure if that will complicate things

Comment: If you do `git remote -v` it should list all the forks that are linked to your local repo. If you need to add another one, you can do so with `git remote add [fork] [url]`. This might be upstream, downstream, alternate, whatever you want the fork to be in relation to origin. Then you can do `git fetch --all` or `git branch -A` to list all the commits on all the branches your local repo knows about. When you cherry-pick, just use the unique sha for the commit and your local repo will find it. If you don't mind, please accept this answer. Thanks! : )

Comment: @heavyqtuser: A "fork" (which is actually a GitHub or Bitbucket or other web server thing) is just an ordinary clone from your own Git's point of view. The actual implementation, on the web server, is that they do a `git clone` (usually with a lot of magic flags behind the scenes to share storage) *and* also record some sort of linkage (also behind the scenes), so a fork really *is* a clone, it's just a clone with extra glue that your Git can't see and doesn't care about.

Answer (score 0):

Stash your changes

```
git stash
```

pull your coworkers changes

```
git pull
```

re-apply your stashed changes

```
git stash pop
```

In case there are conflicts the stash will not be automatically delete. After you resolved the conflicts, use

```
git stash drop
```

See [man git-stash](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) and [Stashing and Cleaning](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) for more info about stashing.